# How to echo only a part of a data in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, echo

I have the following lines of some data (in the form of an array) that I extracted. I need help using the preg_match PHP function. Can it be used here to echo only specific data i.e 'name' as "Lester" and 'screen name' as "lestaaaaaaa" ? I have no idea how regex works and I'm pretty bad at it. Can somebody guide me how I can do it in php?
Thanks in advance!

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'id' => int 46074289
  public 'id_str' => string '46074289' (length=8)
  public 'name' => string 'Lester' (length=6)
  public 'screen_name' => string 'lestaaaaaaa' (length=11)
  public 'location' => string 'Planet Dirt.' (length=12)
  public 'description' => string 'Amateur web developer | Photoshop lover | Alcohol scholar |  Internet practitioner' (length=82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a regex. From the above code, i see that the variables are inside an object. You can just use `$object->name` and `$object->screen_name` to access the varaibels.

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php